# Joining 2 queries...error while pulling certain fields out

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to join 2 queries & get certain columns out of the join. But I am getting an error. Can you please help me understand where I am going wrong -

```
SELECT X.*,Y.* FROM
(
    (
    SELECT  
        C1,C2,C3
        COUNT(C4) AS CNT    -- count
    FROM [dbo].[Tb1]
    WHERE C1 <> 0 AND    -- amount not = zero
        C2 = 'F'        -- flag
    GROUP BY C1,C2,C3
    HAVING COUNT(C4) > 1
    )X
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Tb1])Y
    ON
        X.C1 = Y.C1            
    AND X.C2 = Y.C2            
    AND X.C3=Y.C3             
    AND X.C4=Y.C4             
)
```

The first query helps me get the duplicates & the second query will help me get the other fields out of the same table.

Thanks.

Comment: I got through it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @anir, you can post the answer to your question

Comment: @RADAR - First of all in my case, I should not have used X.C4=Y.C4 in the join condition. In case its required in any case, the correct condition would have been AND X.CNT=Y.C4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution #1:

```
SELECT X.*,Y.* FROM
--( <-- (1) comment  this line
    (
    SELECT  
        C1,C2,C3, -- <-- (2) add , after C3
        COUNT(C4) AS CNT    -- count
    FROM [dbo].[Tb1]
    WHERE C1 <> 0 AND   -- amount not = zero
        C2 = 'F'        -- flag
    GROUP BY C1,C2,C3
    HAVING COUNT(C4) > 1
    )X
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Tb1])Y
    ON
        X.C1 = Y.C1            
    AND X.C2 = Y.C2            
    AND X.C3=Y.C3             
    AND X.CNT=Y.C4 <-- see   anir's comment            
--) <-- (3) comment  this line
```

Or

Solution #2:

```
SELECT  X.*, Y.* 
FROM
(
    SELECT  
        C1,C2,C3, 
        COUNT(C4) AS CNT    -- count
    FROM [dbo].[Tb1]
    WHERE 
        C1 <> 0 AND    -- amount not = zero
        C2 = 'F'       -- flag
    GROUP BY C1,C2,C3
    HAVING COUNT(C4) > 1
) X
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tb1] Y
ON  X.C1 = Y.C1            
    AND X.C2 = Y.C2            
    AND X.C3=Y.C3             
    AND X.CNT=Y.C4 <-- see   anir's comment
```

Note #1: When CNT > 1 and x.C1 , y.C1 contains NULLs then X.C1 = Y.C1 <=> `NULL = NULL` which is evaluated to UNKNOWN if ANSI_NULLS is ON. This means that these rows will be eliminated from final resultset. The same applies to X.C2 = Y.C2 and X.C3=Y.C3.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS T1
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SELECT CASE WHEN NULL = NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS T2
/*
T1
-----------
0

T2
-----------
1
*/
```

Note #2:  ["In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).

Or

Solution #3:

```
SELECT  y.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT  x.*, COUNT(x.C4) OVER(PARTITION BY x.C1, x.C2, x.C3) AS CNT    -- count
    FROM    [dbo].[Tb1] x
    WHERE 
        x.C1 <> 0 AND   -- amount not = zero
        x.C2 = 'F'      -- flag
        -- AND x.C1 IS NOT NULL AND x.C2 IS NOT NULL AND x.C3 IS NOT NULL ?
) y
WHERE y.CNT > 1 AND y.CNT = y.C4
```